# Which kernel for which system

Tags: linux, debian, kernel, linux-kernel

I often have issues between the Linux kernel and the hardware I'm using. But I guess this is not new, especially on laptops.

GPU support, WiFi support, hibernation, etc...

Is there a tool that can "scan" you current system and "find" an appropriate kernel ? Or ask you to compile it yourself with specific options.

Comment: Generally speaking, the newer the kernel, the better the support for hardware across the board.

Comment: Please edit by  adding the output of `uname -a` and `lspci -n` , and clarify  the issues.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not such a thing.  The best you can do is to make sure your kernel and all packages are up-to-date for your distribution (`sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`). Then look for specific support for the issues you're having, mentioning your distro name and version, your hardware, and the problem you're having.

Comment: Since the question was taggen 'debian', I'd suggest `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` or `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade linux-image` .

Comment: @schaiba Good catch. That'll teach me to read the tags before answering. I have corrected the answer.